# creating views in play framework 2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created `view.input` package in play framework and then `form.scala.html` file under it. now I want to use redirect in class as below:

```
return ok(form.render(somevalue));
```

here I am not able to get `form` which I have created under `views` and so I am getting an error. why is it so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try:

```
return ok(views.html.input.form.render(someValue));
```

or even:

```
import views.html.input.form;

...
    return ok(form.render(someValue));
...
```

but in such case it's best to build view's name with package prefix for visual differencing them from views from `views` package `/app/views/input/inputForm.scala.html`:

```
import views.html.input.inputForm;

...
return ok(inputForm.render(someValue));
```

Comment: I am getting error 'package views.input.html does not exist'. _Steps I followed to add create views (I am using eclipse IDE)_  **First**- Created package under  '/app'  with name **views.input**     **Second**- Added  'html'  file under it with name **form.scala.html**. Is this is the proper way of creating views?

Comment: Yes, but Eclipse will not find your class until you build it with the Play console. Try a `play run` and see if Play throws a compile error.

Comment: @nico_ekito I added other possibilities, hope, you won't mind ;)

Comment: @Nishikant: I'd recommend testing the IntelliJ Idea as IDE it works with Play 2.0 and is supposed to be even more suited

Comment: @MarcusbiesiorBiesioroff - yes, I will try to use Intelli J, I don't know why sometime eclipse behave weird with play. Thanks for your answer.